# Border around formatted text in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text

I'm trying to create a block of text with formatting and I want to surround it with a border. I've tried the *Flow into frame* feature, but that removes formatting (I would like line breaks, spaces, bold, etc...).

Right now, I'm manually drawing a rectangle around it and aligning it (using the align and distribute functions). Is there a way to automate this and produce consistent results?

My current technique does not guarantee even spacing from the border to the text of multiple boxes like these.

Comment: [Here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1289009) is an extension (not tried) which creates a rectangle for
the bounding box of each selected object.

Comment: "Topic not found" - wrong link?

Comment: It's curious, there isn't a permalink to the topic: now the link is [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/128900). Try using a google search for `inkscape frame around text site:www.ruby-forum.com` it *should* be the first result.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I still can't find this extension!

Comment: @HermanToothrot It seems that the page doesn't exist anymore. But the answer of Sean Colsen shows a simple and effective way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes! Here is the end result:

[image: end result]

**Step by step:**

1. Create some flowed text by using the text tool to first drag a rectangle and then type.

[image: step1]

2. Separately, create a rectangle roughly around the text (really, the rectangle can be anywhere)

[image: step2]

3. With the rectangle selected, chose "Path" > "Linked Offset". Then grab the small diamond and drag it in to make a second, smaller rectangle.

[image: step3]

4. Select the text and the smaller rectangle and choose "Text" > "Flow into frame". Then select the smaller rectangle and remove the stroke to make it invisible. Now the text will flow within the smaller (invisible) rectangle, which is dynamically linked to the shape of the larger (visible) rectangle.

[image: step6]

5. Then, if you like, you can add a small border radius on the visible rectangle and you get this nice looking result.

[image: end result]

6. If you do need to modify the space between the text and the rectangle, you can carefully select it by grabbing it with the text and the subtracting the text from the selection, or you can drill down to it within the XML Editor. When you do get it selected, then you can adjust the margin as follows:

[image: adjustments]

7. Finally, group the text and the two rectangles, and you're all set!

Comment: That's a great trick. I still can't believe that something that simple requires so many steps.

Comment: Great! However, when I make the inner rectangle invisible (by clicking the hidden button on the properties or setting its color to #00000000) then I can't grab it anymore or even see its outlines. Is there a solution for this problem ?

Comment: I found a solution : Object > Unhide All.

Comment: But grouping the objects isn't stable (at least with 0.91 on osx).

Comment: Step 6 is easier at least in 0.92. Just select the text and notice the status bar tells you to hit Shift-D if you want to "look up frame". That gets the invisible frame selected, then hit F2 for the node select tool, and you should see the resizing diamond.

Comment: @maxagaz isn't there any update of a quicker way to do this? It makes the workflow for diagrams very slow.

Comment: To make matters worse, if you make a template and copy it, the copies will not preserve the link between rectangles or even remember the inner rectangle's styling and z-order.

Comment: Hi, since we are now using Inkscape 1.x, and you update the answer to support the new Inkscape release? I see there is no menu item:  "Path" > "Linked Offset" now in the new release.

Comment: @ollydbg23 I am using v1.2, the "Linked Offset" does exist in the Path menu. And the tips in the answer work ok as I jsut tested.

Comment: Hi, @bruin thanks for the comment, I just checked this option in my Inkscape 1.0.2, indeed it does exist. While following the steps in this answer, I'm no sure how to select the inner rectangle. I mean the rectangle around the text, not the outer rectangle. In my test, I only see the outer rectangle.

Comment: [3, With the rectangle selected, chose "Path" > "Linked Offset". Then grab the small diamond and drag it in to make a second, smaller rectangle. ], In this step, which rectangle should I select, I have only the outer rectangle which is created in step 2, and after I click the "Linked Offset", which small diamond should I do? I would like someone can make a screen cast, it looks like Inkscape changes from version to version, and the answer does not fit to the latest 1.0.2 version I'm using, thanks.

Comment: To apply "Path > Linked Offset" command, you need to select the first rectangle (or outter rectcangle). Actually, before applying this command, you only have one rectangle which is the first one; After applying the command, you will see the 2nd rectangle which is inside the first rectangle (as shown in this reply).  I guess what you encountered is that, either, you did not select the 1st rect before invoking the cmd, or, the command works differently on your side somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.0 you can use more easy approach - Path Effects. See a good tutorial here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/146898/178571