# Scaling Text and Associated Objects

Tags: inkscape, text, resize

I'm making a huge number of "labels" that consist of text and a translucent background box.
 - I'm looking for something that will, if I were to change the length of the text or the size of the font, that would ensure the margin between text and the exterior of the box remains the exact same.
That way, I could avoid having to resize the box background every time, manually and precisely.
[image: pl_upward]

*If the text "short" was edited to "reaallly long", the box would grow with it*

Comment: maybe you're not familiar with inkscape, but if theres an easy way to do this in another program id love to hear it

Comment: Just found this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/border-around-formatted-text-in-inkscape; very similar, but in reverse, with the text influencing the rectangle szie

Comment: Would filters work for you, too? Or does it have to be an object? Solution that uses filters: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120294/inkscape-for-cartography-fill-the-background-of-a-text