# Text at the center of a rectangle in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am using Inkscape to label a diagram. In the attached image I have shown how I would like to label:

[image]

In Inkscape is there a way to write a text inside a rectangle such that it is always at the center of the rectangle?

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Giri. I think that [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/border-around-formatted-text-in-inkscape) could get you a hint.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Click on the page with the text tool, and type some text
2. Draw a rectangle around it
3. Select both, and do *Text > Flow into Frame*
4. Highlight all the text with the Text tool, and click the Align Centre button along the top.
5. Using the Select and Transform tool (F1)*, reposition the text so that it's centred.

That's it really. You can type new text inside and it will be centred. You can group it, copy and paste more copies, and edit the text. It should stay centred in the middle.  You can also resize the rectangle, if you need to fit more text in. Even mutli line text will work.  If you don't want to scale the stroke of the rectangle when you are resizing it, go into *Edit > Preferences > Behaviour > Transforms*, and deselect the "Scale stroke width" option

[image]

*Edit: In Inkscape 1.0.x the shortcut key is now <kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: Dear Mr. Billy Kerr, please correct me if I am wrong. I guess step 4 will help me to center align the text horizontally (automatically). And using step 5, I have to manually center align the text vertically. But my concern is that while executing step 5, as I would be manually aligning the text vertically, it's prone to human errors. Also the results achieved in step 4 might be lost. Is there a way out of this?

Comment: There's no way to align text vertically inside a text box unfortunately, however I suppose you could use the Align & Distribute panel (Shift+Ctrl+A), select both text and rectangle, and hit the "Centre on horizontal axis" button.

Comment: This will be easier in Inkscape 1.0, using 'Bounding Box' and 'Offset' LPEs in combination. Better to group the text and the object with the effect before moving them around, though, else it will get messed up (dislocated) pretty quickly.

Comment: @Moini - yes I already mentioned grouping them in my answer.

Comment: I wasn't referring to your answer, with the grouping hint, Billy, but to the LPEs I described.

Comment: I follow Billy Kerr's method, and If I need to put the text in the box's center, I have to hit "Centre on horizontal axis" and then hit the "Centre on vertical axis". Is there any simple method?

Comment: One problem I see is that if I reshape the rectangle, than the centered text also get reshaped, and the text are shown so badly. Any way to keep the text shape while the bounding box changed?

Comment: @ollydbg23 This isn't a problem. The box can be scaled without scaling or distorting the text. [See example](https://imgur.com/7LEl9R4)

Comment: Hi, Billy Kerr, you shown me the gif that the rectangle and the text are not bundled. Which means change the rectangle does not changes the text. While, in my steps, when after the step: `Select both, and do Text > Flow into Frame`, the text and the rectangle just get bundled, and when I scale the rectangle, the inner text get distorted.

Comment: OK, I found there are two kinds of entering text. One is just select the Text tool, and click on the panel, then enter the text. Another way is, select the Text tool, use the mouse to drag a rectangle on the panel, then enter the text in the rectangle. Note the second method's rectangle is not the same one as the flow chart's rectangle. I used to use the second way to enter the text, and this cause the distorted text issue when I bundle the text with other rectangle.

Comment: Is there a simple way or automatic way that the text is always centered in the rectangle? For me, if I follow your steps, I have always click the "Centre on horizontal axis" and then hit the "Centre on vertical axis" after I change the size of the rectangle. Thanks.

Comment: @ollybg23 - this is an old question, and I answered it for Inkscape 0.92.  The newest 1.0.x versions have Live Path Effects which could be used instead to centre text in a box automatically. If I get time I'll post another answer here.

Comment: @ollydbg23 I've now added a new answer, take a look.

Comment: Some new information about how to adjust the size and the position of the bundled text and rectangle. If I only select the rectangle, and scale and pan the rectangle don't make the inner text distorted. But after the scale and pan, the rectangle and the text are not aligned correctly. I still have to select the two objects, and click the "Centre on horizontal axis" and then hit the "Centre on vertical axis" again. This makes it some tedious operation. Some hint: for the alignment works, I found that select the relative to "Drawing" is a better way instead of the default "Selection Area".

Comment: I follow the first 4 steps, and for the last step, I don't tweak the vertical by the "Transform" tool, instead, I use the "Align and Distribute" tool, see the gif screen cast of the operation (https://imgur.com/i3S5Idb). Please notice that once you resize the rectangle, you have to click the "Center on the horizontal axis" button. Personally I expect there is an option in the step 4 which let me choose both the vertical and horizontal centered. Maybe a Inkscape plugin/add-on is needed to implement this feature.

Comment: I finally found that `inkscape` is not good at drawing flowchart, luckily, I found another open source tool called `draw.io`, which have standalone desktop applications and web online versions, I wrote a tutorial about how to import SVG files to latex files, `https://github.com/asmwarrior/LatexImportSVGTutorial`, because I use SVG files for technical documents.

Answer (score 3):

Further to comments here, I've decided to add another answer as an update, since Inkscape 1.0 now has Live Path Effects which can be used for this. This idea was first suggested by @Moini in the comments.

Anyway, here's how to set it up.

1. Draw a rectangle, any size.
2. Type some text, select the text object, and copy it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Select the rectangle you drew previously, and do *Path > Path Effects*
4. Click the **+** icon in the Path Effects dialog
5. Select the Bounding Box LPE (live path effect)

[image]

6. In the Path Effects dialog hit the "Linked to Path in Clipboard" button. This will make the bounding box surround the text. Move the text, and the box will follow.

[image]

7. Click the **+** icon again to add another Path Effect, and this time choose the Offset LPE.

[image]

8. In the Path Effects dialog, increase the offset until you are happy.

You can now retype the text, and the surrounding box will expand to fit the text. You can also scale the text, and the box will expand to fit it.

[image]

Comment: HI, Billy Kerr, thanks. You second answer by using the Live Path Effects works. But I still have an issue is: by using the LPE, now the rectangle size is basically depend on the text boundary. When design my flow chart, I would like to make some rectangles which have the same size, but the internal text are different. So, I'd see if there is a method that which locates the text in the center of the rectangle, but when the rectangle changes, the text is always locates in the center. I may call this a constraint. Thanks.

Comment: Another issue when I use the LPE method is: I can't copy/paste the whole block to make many clones. When I pastes the whole blocks, I see only the internal text get copied and pasted.

Comment: @ollydbg23 Group it and you can make a copy.  The text is still editable. Yeah this method adjusts the size of rectangle to fit the text. You may have to use another method. I can't think of any that would work automatically to centre the text inside rectangles of constant size. I mean, there are alignment tools in Inkscape, but you have to select and hit buttons to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think there are two main methods which are the two answers you posted here for this question. I try to follow the question you posted in Apr 10 '20, but I think I can't get the exact result(you shown in the gif in that answer) when I follows the steps in Inkscape 1.0.2, so can you update the old answers for the latest Inkscape? Thanks.

Comment: @ollydbg23 - the old answer still works for Inkscape 1.0.x.  I just tested it. The only real difference is that the Select and Transform Tool shortcut is now changed to **s**, rather than **F1**. Other than that, there is no difference in the steps.

Comment: @BillyKerr When using Inkscape 1.2.2, in step 6, when clicking on **Linked to Path in Clipboard**, the rectangle disappears. I have not tried earlier Inkscape versions. Where does the rectangle disappear to? Subsequent steps will not be workable because the rectangle is lost. Is this a defect?

Comment: @bgoodr not sure, could be a bug. I can also replicate the problem.

Comment: @bgoodr - It does seem to work in Inkscape 1.3 now, so whatever the bug was, it seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer using Text > Flow into Frame doesn't allow me to easily (?) vertically centre the text.

The answer using Live Path Effects will remove any rounded corners from the rectangle.

There is another way to do this that might not suit everyone, but works well enough for me:

1. Create the Rectangle and Text.
2. Make sure that the text is small enough to fit in the Rectangle (roughly position it inside the Rectangle).
3. Select both of them.
4. Object > Align and Distribute (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), Center on vertical axis, Center on horizontal axis.
5. Group them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

Comment: This is the best answer, and the closest to the intuitive "snap to center" or "text box" functionality you see in programs like PowerPoint. I just tried this in Inkscape 1.2 (beta) and I don't need to ungroup them and re-align when changing the text. It continues to stay centered as long as I don't add a new line of text.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really need to ungroup it. Double-clicking lets you enter the group and edit objects within the group, including text.

Comment: OK, updated the answer to reflect that ungrouping is not necessary.